# Ideal sets of polynomials

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory, ideals

> The set I of all polynomials of even degree in Z(x) is not ideal because $1 \in I$ and $I \ne Z(x)$. Or consider $1 \in I$, $1x=x \notin I$.

I understand the second reasoning since x is in Z(x) so by definitiion of ideals, 1x or x1 has to be in I but it is not so I is not ideal--am i right?

Also, I am totally lost for the first reasoning--why $I \ne Z(x)$ mean I is not ideal? And Is the above also true in Q(x) setting? (I would assume so.)

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $I$ is an ideal of $\mathbb Z[x]$ and that $1 \in I$. Then, for any $f(x) \in \mathbb Z[x]$ we have $f(x) = 1f(x) \in I$, so, $\mathbb Z[x] \subseteq I$ and then $I = \mathbb Z[x]$.

Comment: oh thank you it is so simple and obvious, im so dumb...is there any theory(s) on showing whether a ring/set is ideal or not btw?